# How to plot multiple variables of a data.table in R?

Tags: r, data.table, data-visualization

I have a time series that has a DateTime variable and 4 more variables, which are measured over time.
I'm trying to create a function in R which gets the data set (as a data.table) and creates 4 plots, each plot showing one of the four variables (y axis) against time (x axis).
I already found out that I can create multiple plots by using

```
par(mfrow=c(4,1))
```

But the problem is that I don't know how to reference each of the 4 columns in the "plot" function.

If I do a single plot without a function, it looks like this:

```
plot(DT[,DateTime],DT[,VAR1],type="l",ylab="VAR1")
```

This is exactly the line which I want for VAR1...VAR4 using a function. Note that I do not want a plot which depicts all 4 variables in a single plot, but rather 4 plots, one for each variable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
lapply(c("VAR1", "VAR2", "VAR3", "VAR4"), function(x){ 
    plot(DT[,DateTime], DT[, ..x], type="l", ylab=x)
})
```

Comment: `lapply` is useful if you want a return value. If you are after the side effect of plotting, a `for` loop is more appropriate.

Comment: Also, `DT[[x]]` should be more efficient than `DT[,x,with=F]`.